# How can I allow unauthorized access to a child route whose parent has an AuthGuard in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular4-router

My Angular 4 app has parent routes set up in the file `app.module.ts` using lazy loading (`loadChildren`). Some routes require authentication (using `canActivate`) and some do not:

```js
// app.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  // Paths that require authentication
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
      { path: 'customer-locator', loadChildren: './customer-locator/customer-locator.module#CustomerLocatorModule' }
    ],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  // Paths that do not require authentication
  { 
    path: 'login', 
    component: LoginComponent 
  }
];
```

Child routes are set up inside each corresponding module. For example, for child routes in `CustomerLocatorModule`, they have been placed in `customer-locator.module.ts`:

```js
// customer-locator.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {  // REQUIRES AUTHENTICATION
    path: '',
    component: CustomerLocatorComponent
  },
  {  // SHOULD NOT REQUIRE AUTHENTICATION
    path: 'edit-customer/:customerId',
    component: EditCustomerComponent
  }
]
```

As it is currently set up, all child routes under `path: ''` require authentication to be accessed.

Is it possible for a child route (in this case, the one pointing to `EditCustomerComponent`) to NOT require authentication, given that its parent route (`customer-locator`) does require authentication?

Comment: Can you move the canActivate to only the 'admin' path? Then it won't guard the customer-locator path.

Comment: @DeborahK The problem is that there is a child path inside `customer-locator` that does require authentication (`path: ''`), and one that doesn't (`path: 'edit-customer/:customerId'`).

Comment: Remove it from the top level path and just add it to the paths that need it.

Answer (score 2):

All you're doing here is grouping your routes. This means you can also do

```
// app.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  // Paths that require authentication
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: 'customer-locator', loadChildren: './customer-locator/customer-locator.module#CustomerLocatorModule' }
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
    ],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  // Paths that do not require authentication
  { 
    path: 'login', 
    component: LoginComponent 
  }
];
```

You're just splitting a group into two groups. Is that what you want ?

Comment: I cannot have the entire `customer-locator` path without `canActivate: [AuthGuard]` since some of its child routes (`path: ''`) require authentication. The problem is that some child routes (`path: 'edit-customer/:customerId'`) do not require authentication.

Comment: Then you should add guard to customer locator riuter. It's not possible to allow some child routes not to have authentication when parent requires it. At least not trivial to implement.

Comment: it worked i made another parent inside main parent so it looks liek something: GrandParent > Parent > childs with guard / childs without guards.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the best way, but you can get the path/url that has been requested and do some checking, with [ActivatedRouteSnapshot](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot).

In your guard:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
  //route has a snapshof of the current route
  //check the route and with an if statement, return observable of(true) if the route is in your whitelist
}
```